# Creating a post-build step in Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode

I'm actually looking for a genuine "post build" phase - not the Run script stage. The reason for this is that I want to do some parsing of a target's build-state.dat which is where Xcode puts all of its build output.

The problem is that this file isn't actually created until after the build has succeeded or failed, thus anything in the Run Script phase can't see it.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a Shell Script Target that has the product you want to analyze as its dependency, and parse the file in the Shell Script Target?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but unfortunately, the build-state.dat file of the dependent target is not yet created at that point. Basically it doesn't show up until the process is complete, which is essentially once the build botton goes from grayed out to active again.

Comment: I don't think you understand what @mipadi is saying- he isn't talking about adding a Run Shell Script Build Phase to your existing Target, instead he is saying you should create an entirely new Target, a Shell Script Target that just has one Build Phase that runs your script. Then you add your original Target as a dependency for the new Target, and then build the new Target, which will first build the old Target, and then only after that fully completes, will build the new Target, thus running your script.